# unfortunately, MyOwnSQLite has stopped

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have encounter a runtime error of "unfortunately, MyOwnSQLite has stopped",while doing this tutorial from http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html

Logcat:

-error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

-(1) no such table: Zomibedatabase

-Error inserting Name=Jenny
-android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Zombiedatabase (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT   INTO Zombiedatabase(Name) VALUES (?)

Adapter.java

```
package com.example.myownsqlite;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Adapter{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Zombiedatabase";
    public static final String DATA_TABLE_NAME = "Mytable";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;

    public static final String EMPLOYEE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String EMPLOYEE_NAME = "Name";


    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DB = "create table " + DATA_TABLE_NAME +" (" 
            + EMPLOYEE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + EMPLOYEE_NAME + " text not null);";
    //      + EMPLOYEE_PAY + " text not null"
    //      + EMPLOYEE_POST + "text not null);";


    private SQLiteHelper sqlitehelp;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private Context context;


    public Adapter(Context c){
          context = c;
         }

//Methods
    //I. read and write
    public Adapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqlitehelp = new SQLiteHelper (context,DATABASE_NAME,null,VERSION);
        db = sqlitehelp.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public Adapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException{
        sqlitehelp = new SQLiteHelper (context,DATABASE_NAME,null,VERSION);
        db = sqlitehelp.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //II. Close
    public void close(){
    sqlitehelp.close();
    }

    //III. Inserting Data
    public long insert(String content1){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(EMPLOYEE_NAME,content1);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    }

    //IV. Delete all
    public int deleteall(){
        return db.delete(DATABASE_NAME,null,null);
    }

    //V.Queue all
    public Cursor queueall(){
            String[] columns = new String[] {EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME};
            Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_NAME, columns, null,null,null,null,null,null);
//http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html
            return cursor;
    }


     public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

          public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
           super(context, name, factory, version);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DB);
          }

          @Override
          public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }
     }  
}
```

Main Activity

```
package com.example.myownsqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Adapter avatar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listemployee = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

        avatar = new Adapter(this);
        avatar.openToWrite();

        avatar.insert("Jenny");
        avatar.insert("Jane");
        avatar.insert("Jess");

        Cursor cursor = avatar.queueall();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{avatar.EMPLOYEE_NAME};
          int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row,cursor,from,to);

        listemployee.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        avatar.close();

    }


}
```

Comment: i not sure if anyone can help you ... you copy code from tutorial, replace some things and code stops working ... programming is more difficult then copying

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html - the insert method requires the table name, not database name.

Comment: As @Selvin said, please don't copy code from tutorials, those code are used as example not to copy, if you want to learn something please take time and learn it.

Comment: I agree. Copy and paste is never a good idea. If you do not understand something, look it up in the official API docs.

Comment: anyway this tutorial isn't good .. it using deprecated `startManagingCursor` it also closing Database but Cursor is still opened it will lead to errors with "large cursors"

Comment: dear selvin, what should i use instead of startManagingCursor.

Comment: thanks for your feedbacks, dear alberto and selvin, could i seek your advice on how to learn programming if i am not suppposed to study the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the table name instead of the database name when you're inserting, same with other methods (crud):

```
public long insert(String content1){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EMPLOYEE_NAME,content1);
    return db.insert(DATA_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alberto, to add on, another errors is that 
the database and string name need to be in uppercase.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ZOMBIEDATA";
public static final String DATA_TABLE_NAME = "TABLE";
```